# RC filter loss amplitude

Tags: pwm, filter

[image]

I made a RC filter with R=200ohm and C= 2.2uF, I want to filter this PWM in the figure with 10k frequency, and get a Sinusoide with 50hz, but in this case I loss amplitude how i can do this???

Comment: What is the source impedance generating the PWM and what is the load?

Comment: It looks like the peak voltage of the PWM is the same as the peak voltage of the sinewave before it. If so, then the PWM duty cycle needs to approach 100% at the peaks of the synthesized part of the wave. It's hard to tell from your waveforms as shown, but it looks like it doesn't get there -- especially given the amount of "fuzz" on the upper waveform near the peaks. What is the maximum PWM duty cycle you're using?

Comment: @ThePhoton made this in MatLab the load is a Resistence with 10k, and the PWM is the output of a full-bridge inverter , Snubber resistance Rs = 1e5 is this what you are ask me?

Comment: @DaveTweed I don't define a fix duty cycle, I compare a triangular wave 10khz with a sinusoidal wave 50hz and it will generate pwm duty cycle...

Comment: So, what is the maximum duty cycle you get at the output of the comparator? It isn't a difficult question. Maybe you need to adjust the relative amplitudes of the two inputs.

Comment: I solved my problem , thanks everyone for help me! Best regarts

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the inductance instead the resistance
-->L = 200/(2*%pi*10000)
 L  =
    0.0031831
around 3.2 mH U can use small SMD standard 1000uH in the serial line (3x1000) 
If it's value is too high, you can try to increase the capacitance, but it will decrease the amplitude